# Is Firebase A/B testing suported for REACT?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am looking in to implementing A/B testing in an REACT app. Is Firebase A/B testing suported, or not?
Is there an alternative if not?

The is a similiar question on StackOwerflow but it's 12 months old, maybe since they implemented it?

Also while we're here. 
What about other Firebase services, are they supported for REACT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this npm package to set up react native + firebase :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase

and use the supported 'remote-config' feature to do A/B testing as suggested here :

[Unable to include AB Testing for React Native application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867960/unable-to-include-ab-testing-for-react-native-application)